# Capturing local scope variables with junit or mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

So I am trying to write a test with `junit 5`
Lets say I have a class:

```
Class Hello {
    Public void doSomething(ObjectA a) {
        ObjB b = some logic to map A to B
    }
}
```

Is there a way in java which I can use to capture the contents of `objB` and test its contents?

Comment: No, create a class `AToBMapper` which is injected into `Hello` and test that separately.

Comment: No, you shouldn't be testing the contents of `b`, but its effect.  What does your method do with `b` after it's created it?  Focus on testing that the method does the right thing, not on what goes on inside the method.